# WPF Ellipse Black Background

Tags: wpf, background, ellipse

How can I remove the black background color in the corners of the ellipse?

[alt text http://publicimages.s3.amazonaws.com/ellipsewithblackbackground.PNG](http://publicimages.s3.amazonaws.com/ellipsewithblackbackground.PNG)

Thanks,

Comment: Is the Ellipse inside a PopUp control.. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

The AllowsTransparency should be true.